# How to fix: .py file doesn't decode str written in Russian and Belarussian languages from a .yaml file. I'm using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, yaml

I'm creating a test in pyqt. For that I'll have to create a file with prompts. I decided to use yaml. The only problem I have is that I keep on getting some unreadable data as output when I have strings in Russian or Belarussian languages. I'm using pycharm.

I've already googled the information on related problem but in ruby. People asked to use UTF-8 encoding. I made sure I have UTF-8 enebeled in pycharm and then saved the both of the files (.py and .yml). But it didn't help. I'm getting the same thing.

```
testRus:
  - q1:
      qt: абвгдеёжз




import yaml

with open('docRus.yaml', 'r') as f:
    doc = yaml.safe_load(f)

txt = doc["testRus"][0]["q1"]["qt"]
print(txt)
```

I expect to get `'абвгдеёжз'` in the end. Instead I'm getting `'Р°Р±РІРіРґРµС‘Р¶Р·'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the encoding also to the `open` call.

If you change the "with" line to

```
with io.open('1.yaml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

your string will be interpreted correctly.

Comment: @chullspen Please select the answer as the one responding to your question, thanks :)